# Set the button frame fit to the view

Tags: ios, ipad, uibutton, bounds

I want to display a UIButton in the header section of a UITableView. This is the code I have tried

```
    UIView *headerView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0, 285, 44)];

    UIButton *headerViewButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    headerViewButton.frame = CGRectMake(headerView.bounds.size.width * 7/5, headerView.bounds.size.height * 1/4, 320.0, 30.0);
    headerViewButton.backgroundColor = [UIColor grayColor];
    [headerViewButton setTitle:@"Import main list from other field  >" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [headerViewButton addTarget:self
                          action:@selector(buttonPressed:)
                forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];

    [headerView addSubview:headerViewButton];
```

The problem is I am having a hard time adjusting the button frame, so that it fits fine in the landscape mode as well as portrait mode. I am not very comfortable with using Interface Builder. How can I adjust the button frame correctly so that it fits the view.

I have tried using `setAutoresizingMask`

```
UIView *headerView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0, 320, 44)];
UIButton *headerViewButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    headerViewButton.frame = CGRectMake(headerView.bounds.size.width * 7/5, headerView.bounds.size.height * 1/4, 290, 30.0);
    headerViewButton.backgroundColor = [UIColor grayColor];
    [headerViewButton setTitle:@"Import main list from other field  >" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [headerViewButton addTarget:self
                         action:@selector(buttonPressed:)
               forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];

    [headerViewButton setAutoresizingMask:UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleTopMargin|UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth];

    [headerView addSubview:headerViewButton];
```

As the app loads for the first time, the button is missing, but as I change the orientation, the button appears. Every time I try, its the same pattern. The first time the app loads, the button would be missing, and it appears on both orientations after that.

Comment: as rmaddy pointed out, you are setting odd button position: `headerViewButton.frame = CGRectMake(headerView.bounds.size.width * 7/5, headerView.bounds.size.height * 1/4, 290, 30.0);` So `x= headerview.width *1.4 = 320 * 1.4`  which is offscreen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set the button's `autoresizingMask` to appropriate values. The values depend on how you want the button's size and/or position to adjust as its parent view's size changes.

In the code you posted, it is odd that you are making the button wider than its parent view.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting

```
[headerViewButton setAutoresizingMask:UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight|UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth];
```

This way it will be resized as the superview changes. (Works the same as setting autoresizing options in IB)